# Background Push Notifications with Web Apps?

Tags: android, ios, html, push-notification

So a client wants to receive push notifications for certain events, and these push notifications should be delivered at all times, even when an app - or the browser - is closed and therefore not running in the background.

First idea was to use the new web push notifications API in conjunction with a service worker, allowing to (re)use the existing html5 codebase. Now when I understand this correctly this only works when the browser / the PWA is running, though I understand the site itself does not need to be opened and the browser can run in the background. But apparently it is not possible to receive those notifications in realtime when there is no browser(engine) running, correct?

Another approach would be to use an app wrapper like phonegap / cordova, so that the resulting app is more "native", though I think it is more like "pseudo native" as the codebase is still html5+js+css.

Now, my question is:

Will such a wrapper allow me to receive such notifications even if the actual app is not running? I mean this would need a separate background process with capabilities beyond a service worker, correct? So, is this possible withsucha wrapper or do I have the same limitations as with a service worker based implementation (be it a website or PWA)?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this - seems like an issue that nobody really puts out a real answer for

Comment: Nope, I guess this is just a hard limit (i.e. Browser must be running) we have to live with. Maybe it works with a wrapper like phonegap, but haven't tried that. Another thing is that implementing PWA push functionality completely by yourself is quite an endeavour, so we ended up with using OneSignal, which works OK.